# Grape Swagger does not show up Example param

Tags: swagger, ruby-grape, dredd

I'm using grape-swagger gem to produce swagger documentation for dredd.

I have such params:

```rb
params do
  requires :id, type: Integer, documentation: { x: { example: 1 } }
end
```

Grape swagger ignores *example* param.
Instead of this:

```rb
{
  "in": "path",
  "name": "id",
  "type": "integer",
  "format": "int32",
  "required": true,
  "x-example": 1
}
```

I got this:

```rb
{
  "in": "path",
  "name": "id",
  "type": "integer",
  "format": "int32",
  "required": true
}
```

How to send *example* values for test purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger/issues/762) in dredd issues. This solves my problem.
In a nutshell, the solution looks like this:

```rb
module MyApp
  module AddExampleToBodyParam
    module ClassMethods
      private

      def document_description(settings)
        super
        @parsed_param[:example] = settings[:example] if settings[:example]
      end
    end

    def self.prepended(base)
      class << base
        prepend ClassMethods
      end
    end
  end
end

module GrapeSwagger
  module DocMethods
    class ParseParams
      prepend MyApp::AddExampleToBodyParam
    end
  end
end
```

Now,I can proxy *example* value to params body with this:

```rb
expose :some, documentation: { example: 'test' }
```